# Etiquette for inviting to chat: Asking about removing "noise" / "chit chat" from own Meta SE answered questions

Tags: discussion, chat, meta, etiquette, clean-up

I want to clean up my posts on Meta Stack Exchange from noise/chit-chat.

I know that these edits should not invalidate the answers. How should I proceed if I'm unsure about a part? More specifically, I'm interested in using the chat to get feedback / POV from other Meta Stack Exchange users; The more knowledge / awareness the other party has about local culture and quirks, the better.

May ask about editing specific answered questions on the Meta Main chatroom? Is there a protocol to invite to chat with people who regularly participate in Meta SE i.e. mandatory silver / gold tag badge holders?

What about using an annotation tool like Diigo to highlight the parts to be deleted and share an annotated page?

## Sample Question

[How to ask about the origin of certain "rule" and its "ruling" attributes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394632/289691)

The above question was posted last weekend. It has two answers. I already created a chatroom and invited one user who agreed to be invited to chat concerning another post.

Regarding the sample question, there are four regular Meta Stack Exchange Users already participating without counting the upvoters/downvoters

| Action | Count | Unique user names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 31 | 5 |
| Question Votes | 9 (+2 / -7) | N/A |
| Answers Votes | 15 ( +8 / -0, +7 / -0) | N/A |
| Edit the question | 1 | 1 |
| Answer | 2 | 2 |
| Comment the question | 1 | 1 |
| Comment the answers | 3 | 1 |

The idea is to remove all the irrelevant stuff without invalidating the answers without bumping too much the question.

## Related

| Case | Remark | [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) / related guidance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deleted questions | I'm also considering the convenience of undeleteing a few automatically deleted questions. I know I will need to flag those that make sense for moderator attention. I wonder if first I should create a chatroom / an annotated copy with the changes to be done once the question is undeleted. | TBD |

## Annotated Questions

TBD

Comment: I feel like you should be asking these sorts of questions in chat. They're not generally useful to other people.

Comment: This is likely to be dependent on the actual Question and what you want to adjust.  Chat would be especially useful in dealing with the specifics and discussing the extent and alternatives of proposed edits.  I don't see a clear rule to be formulated for this.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yesterday, I commented on a reply that I didn't. I did not successfully invite you . I finally found out how and sent the invitation.

Comment: @hardmath I edited the question to include a sample question.

Answer (score 7):

If removing noise invalidates answers, it means it wasn't noise after all and it shouldn't have  been removed.

What you're asking for is for others to review a question, and spend lots of time and effort to make it better by removing non relevant parts.

This is legit to ask of course, but not push it on people. So I think the best course of action is indeed using chat, but in few steps.

1. Hop to the [main chat room of MSE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), and post there a message like "Who would like to help me out improving my posts, and willing to be invited to chat rooms for each of those?".
2. If you get replies to the above message, you can then start a new chat room for each post you want to improve, and invite those who agreed to help. Or, if there are many posts and to avoid cluttering with many rooms, one room where you'll share the posts you want to improve.
3. If you know of others who are willing to help (e.g. said so in comments) then apply the above for them.

Rule of thumb is: don't just ping or invite people who didn't explicitly agree for this in the first place.

Comment: **Thanks**. I'll ask about the unclear if it can be removed parts only. I'm not looking to ask others to review unnecessary parts based on what the answerers decided to focus on in their answers.  I don't want to demand more time for the Q/A participants if they are not people who like to revisit posts, especially if they have already posted an answer. I know that a group of users prefer to "touch" posts only once, so I will not bother them. Other users like to help with curation tasks continually, but not all like to be invited to chat, not all are active on the main chatroom, etc.