# Blacklist [not-programming-related]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

This is a duplicate of [Can we disallow the use of “belongs-on-xxxxxxx” and “not-programming-related” tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag), but I'm bringing it up again because it sounded last time like "We would blacklist this if we could, but SO doesn't support it", and that's no longer the case.

Most people seem to follow [Shog9's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) of removing [[not-programming-related]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/not-programming-related/info) as they come across it, and the synopsis on the tag info page begins:

> Please do not use this tag.

Is there a reason to not just blacklist it, or was it just that in the past blacklisting didn't exist?

Comment: Well... Might be useful to leave it for the moment, so we can migrate the questions to the NPR site when it comes out of beta...

Comment: @Shog9 I imagine mass-migrating all 769 would be a bad idea, but it might be good for somebody to poke through them and migrate the best ones

Comment: @Shoq - NPR? You think Terry Gross will interview them?

Comment: @Peter: it's no more than they deserve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [allmusic.com](http://image.allmusic.com/00/adg/cov200/drt100/t118/t118524wzb7.jpg))</sub>

This is completed; tag destroyed.